# 'Continue experiences on this device' group policy

Tags: windows, group-policy

In an enterprise or office setting, should I set 'Continue experiences on this device' under the group policy to be disabled? Why should I set it to be disabled, or why shouldn't I set it to be disabled, and what are the consequences if I didn't set it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This policy setting determines whether the Windows device is allowed to participate in cross-device experiences (continue experiences).
>
> If you enable this policy setting, the Windows device is discoverable by other Windows devices that belong to the same user, and can participate in cross-device experiences.
>
> If you disable this policy setting, the Windows device is not discoverable by other devices, and cannot participate in cross-device experiences.
>
> If you do not configure this policy setting, the default behavior depends on the Windows edition. Changes to this policy take effect on reboot.

https://getadmx.com/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.GroupPolicy::EnableCDP

This is probably the description listed from the group policy editor description. Cross device experience is a network service that lets users continue where they left of on another device. It may (probably) have security problems, and it can have security implications with regards to different devices for different tasks, so it may be desirable to disable in some scenarios, whilst it may be unproblematic in other scenarios.

If you don't set it, the default value will depend on the windows edition.

Comment: I like your answers.  People are not so good at voting in here.  Thanks for taking the time to write this.  It's a good answer.  Cheers.